# Font picker in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one requirement in which I want user to allow selecting font type,size and color. I don't want HTML editor which comes. I just want users to select font type,size and color.

It should look like 'Font' option we have in Microsoft Word.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Among which fonts? How do you intend to decide on the repertoire of fonts that can be selected?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making an array with all the web safe fonts, parse that down to an `<option>` menu, and if the user selects something different, check in the array wich corresponding `font-family` that array has and set it in css.

Comment: To begin with, there are no web safe fonts. (If you think e.g. Times New Roman is, try using Android.)